# Btn-group stacking upon window re-size (smaller)

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am making an angular app with HTML, and CSS and have a form with a button group (3 buttons horizontally lined). However, when I make the window smaller, the buttons stack on top of eacother.

It is a class="list-unstyled btn-group" within a class="form-group". How would I resize the buttons to keep them horizontal?

Comment: please show your code, it would be good if you also add the bootstrap tag (I believe you're using it by your class nameS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons stack because the space required is more than space available. Hence, you need to make sure that in smaller windows, space available should be more than equal to space required

You can achieve this by following approaches.

1. Use media queries.

   ```
   @media screen and (min-width:420px) and (max-width:770px) {
       // Write your styles here - reduce padding, font-size, etc
   }
   ```

For e.g. you have an element with class my-class and have font-size as 12px and in screen size from 420 to 770, want font-size as 10px. Then css will look

```
.my-class {
    font-size : 12px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:420px) and (max-width:770px) {
   .my-class {
         font-size : 10px;
    }
}
```

2. Use css frameworks like bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/
3. Use can also introduce javascript (if required)

Comment: I am using bootstrap as well. BTW, where do I put the @media?

Comment: Media queries are your css - Add to css stylesheets added on page. Additionally, if you are using, then cross check your structure, most of the issues will be fixed by changing structure.

Comment: Ok. Where do I link the media to the name of the class it is to use?

Comment: You dont have to link media. Just add your style within that block. For e.g. p { color : red }

Comment: But WHAT is turning red? For instance, we use class names to link "what" would be turning red. So, do we add class names inside the @media tag?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example. Please check.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I understand..... However, I just realized the size of my window is not whats challenging me. It is the size of the modal. I have a modal with the btn-group within in. The stacking of the buttons only happens when the window is closed enough so the window causes the modal to become smaller. How would I deal with this?

Comment: Well, without looking at the code, I will not be able to help you further with this. It will be great if you post your code in an edit block in this question or you can post a new question as well.